Clean the html from API response which includes /n and / characters in notepad++
I receive html response from the API
{"translations":[{"detected_source_language":"EN","text":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n    <title>Testing</title>\n    <style>\n  

I want the cleaned html in my notepad++

But it appears like this.
what have I tried:

But it still isn't enough. There are also stuff like
lang=\"en\"
Is there a feature in Notepad++ to parse it back to a normal HTML completely?
I am using windows os.

What is the problem?

Are you asking how to clean it programmatically? The question you have asked can be answered "by deleting the characters in the view you're looking at", but that may not be what you INTENDED to ask. Please EDIT your post to clarify what you are asking. Include the details of your system, what you have tried, and summarize any research you have done while attempting to solve this yourself.

Updated, hope you now get what I am trying to ask.

@music2myear No. doing it programmatically is easy. Is there a feature in NP++ to quickly do it?

You can do both operations in a single pass:

Ctrl+H
Find what: \\n|\\(?=")
Replace with: LEAVE EMPTY
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
\\n         # a backslash followed by letter n
  |           # OR
\\          # a backslash
(?=")       # positive lookahead, make sure we we have a double quote after


Brilliant. That cleaned it. <3
